# как изменять элементы матрицы в numpy

Tags: python, numpy

у меня есть матрица который создается таким кодом

```
[[j for j in range(1,101)] for i in range(200)]
```

я хочу чтобы получилась матрица где каждый элемент такого вида, можно ли это как то сделать при помощи numpy

```
[array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
    [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
    [41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
    [61, 62, 63, 64, 65],
    [81, 82, 83, 84, 85]]),
array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
    [26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
    [46, 47, 48, 49, 50],
    [66, 67, 68, 69, 70],
    [86, 87, 88, 89, 90]]),
array([[11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
    [31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
    [51, 52, 53, 54, 55],
    [71, 72, 73, 74, 75],
    [91, 92, 93, 94, 95]]),
array([[ 16,  17,  18,  19,  20],
    [ 36,  37,  38,  39,  40],
    [ 56,  57,  58,  59,  60],
    [ 76,  77,  78,  79,  80],
    [ 96,  97,  98,  99, 100]])]
```

в конечной матрице должно быть 200 таких массивов.
Этот элемент я сделал так

```
a = np.array([j for j in range(1,101)]).reshape(5,-1)
np.split(a, [5, 10, 15, 20],axis=1)
```

Comment: В чем конкретная трудность? Разделяйте массивы и объединяйте по нужной оси.

Comment: @СергейКох я так и делаю, я думал можно это сделать как то более элегантно